# TypeError: configurable() got an unexpected keyword argument 'denylist'

Tags: python, deep-learning

I installed the package, but I cannot import it. I get this error:
TypeError: configurable() got an unexpected keyword argument 'denylist'
I appreciate it if you could help me to fix this.
Below you can see the complete error that I got.

```
import trax
```

I installed this package(Deep learning package), and when I import it, I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3afdcd9c7c68> in <module>
----> 1 import trax

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/trax/__init__.py in <module>
     16 """Trax top level import."""
     17 
---> 18 from trax import data
     19 from trax import fastmath
     20 from trax import layers

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/trax/data/__init__.py in <module>
     18 
     19 from trax.data import inputs
---> 20 from trax.data import tf_inputs
     21 
     22 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/trax/data/tf_inputs.py in <module>
    504 
    505 # Makes the function accessible in gin configs, even with all args denylisted.
--> 506 @gin.configurable(denylist=['dataset', 'training'])
    507 def cifar10_no_augmentation_preprocess(dataset, training):
    508   del training

TypeError: configurable() got an unexpected keyword argument 'denylist'
```

I really need to work with this package, and I don't know how to fix it.
My OS: macOS Big Sur
Python version: Python 3.7.4

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
!pip install --upgrade -q gin git+https://github.com/google/trax.git@v1.2.3